# Is it technically possible to install Ubuntu Server on a Android Device?

Tags: ubuntu, android

Can I install a normal Ubuntu Server on a Android device?

Do I have to compile it first?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/508336/can-i-install-ubuntu-14-04-server-on-my-android-phone

Answer (score 2):

As long as Arm64 is supported, and to this day it is:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-18.04-server-arm64.iso.torrent

Don't misunderstand me, I mean it should be technically feasible, but as I fail to see your requirements in the question, I also doubt this Q&A will help someone else.